# How to initialize a multiple choice alert dialog with every option selected?

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

Currently I have a alert dialog with multiple select boxes, I want to check all select boxes when the user opens the dialog. I've seached but couldn't find a way to select all select boxes without showing the dialog first.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.custom_dialog);
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                selectedItems.add(indexSelected);
            }
            else if (selectedItems.contains(indexSelected)) {
                selectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
            }
        }
    }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
         // TODO
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            filterDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    filterDialog = builder.create();
    filterDialog.show(); // only works when I show the dialog first, but I want every option to be selected without showing first
    ListView list = filterDialog.getListView();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {
        list.setItemChecked(i, true);
        selectedItems.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
    }
}
```

This will open the dialog immediately and select all select boxes. Is there any way to select all boxes without showing the dialog first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send the checked items in the builder params itself like this,

```
boolean[] checkedItems = new boolean[items.lengthh];

for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (selectedItems.contains(i)) {
        checkedItems[i] = true;
    } else {
        checkedItems[i] = false;
    }
}

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    selectedItems.add(indexSelected);
                }
                else if (selectedItems.contains(indexSelected)) {
                    selectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
                }
            }
        }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // TODO
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                filterDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```